# C# Sudoku Board Generator

Tags: c#, sudoku

First off, yes I have searched and no I did not find a relevant answer to my question. I am trying to create a Sudoku Board in C#. I believe my cells are correct and my "Game board" class is correct, however I cannot get an actual board generated. I am sure I am missing something obvious, but what I am looking to do is to have my code output an actual board. Without this part, I cannot test my cells class to make sure I can actually play.

**Speficially I was trying to take my code and generate a display of what was being coded so that I would be able to properly troubleshoot the rest of my code. To clarify, what I have down is data, but there was not an output to display. After going through several tutorials to push a display by trying to create a Grid, using Console.WriteLine(), and trying to display using a secondary list, I came up short. The display problem has been answered by John, who helped me specify the question in the string of comments. I would like for this to be kept available in searches since I think a lot of people run into this issue but the search results are slim to none in my opinion**

What I have for my main program is a list of cells that are to be filled in (I am testing by creating the board manually). The source code is as follows:

```
namespace Sudoku
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                Board board = new Board();

                board.SetCellValue(1, 3, 4);
                board.SetCellValue(1, 5, 5);
                board.SetCellValue(1, 9, 2);

                board.SetCellValue(2, 1, 1);
                board.SetCellValue(2, 4, 2);

                board.SetCellValue(3, 1, 7);
                board.SetCellValue(3, 3, 5);
                board.SetCellValue(3, 4, 1);
                board.SetCellValue(3, 6, 8);
                board.SetCellValue(3, 7, 9);

                board.SetCellValue(4, 1, 3);
                board.SetCellValue(4, 2, 5);
                board.SetCellValue(4, 3, 2);
                board.SetCellValue(4, 6, 1);
                board.SetCellValue(4, 7, 7);
                board.SetCellValue(4, 8, 8);

                board.SetCellValue(5, 2, 6);
                board.SetCellValue(5, 5, 7);
                board.SetCellValue(5, 8, 5);

                board.SetCellValue(6, 2, 8);
                board.SetCellValue(6, 3, 7);
                board.SetCellValue(6, 4, 6);
                board.SetCellValue(6, 7, 4);
                board.SetCellValue(6, 8, 3);
                board.SetCellValue(6, 9, 1);

                board.SetCellValue(7, 3, 6);
                board.SetCellValue(7, 4, 3);
                board.SetCellValue(7, 6, 7);
                board.SetCellValue(7, 7, 5);
                board.SetCellValue(7, 9, 8);

                board.SetCellValue(8, 6, 2);
                board.SetCellValue(8, 9, 4);

                board.SetCellValue(9, 1, 8);
                board.SetCellValue(9, 5, 1);
                board.SetCellValue(9, 7, 3);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

From this, what do I need to add to make the code generate an actual board? I believe the problem is that the data is generated, but there is no specific output to push anything to display the code as a board.

I have a `Board` class and a `Cell` class that I can provide as well if that helps. I'm reaching out on here because I have gone back through tutorials, other websites, and a friend but we can't seem to figure this out.

Edit:

Here is my Board class, which the intention is to handle the basic logic of the board, leaving the board blank:

```
namespace Sudoku
{
    public class Board
    {
       public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }

        public Board()
        {
            Cells = new List<Cell>();


            for (int row = 1; row < 10; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 1; column < 10; column++)
                {
                    Cells.Add(new Cell(row, column));
                }
            }
        }


        public void SetCellValue(int row, int column, int value)
        {
            Cell activeCell = Cells.Single(x => (x.Row == row) && (x.Column == column));

            activeCell.Value = value;

            foreach (Cell cell in Cells.Where(s => !s.IsSolved && (s.Row == row)))
            {
                cell.PotentialValues.Remove(value);
            }
            foreach (Cell square in Cells.Where(s => !s.IsSolved && (s.Column == column)))
            {
                square.PotentialValues.Remove(value);
            }
            foreach (Cell cell in Cells.Where(s => !s.IsSolved && (s.Block == activeCell.Block)))
            {
                cell.PotentialValues.Remove(value);
            }
            foreach (Cell cell in Cells.Where(s => !s.IsSolved && (s.PotentialValues.Count == 1)))
            {
                SetCellValue(cell.Row, cell.Column, cell.PotentialValues[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Cell class, which my intention of the cell class is to manage the IO of each cell:

```
namespace Sudoku
{
    public class Cell
    {
        private readonly List<int> values = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        internal enum Blocks
        {
            UpperLeft,
            UpperMiddle,
            UpperRight,
            MiddleLeft,
            Middle,
            MiddleRight,
            LowerLeft,
            LowerMiddle,
            LowerRight
        }

        public int Row { get; private set; }
        public int Column { get; private set; }

        internal Blocks Block
        {
            get
            {
                if (Row < 4)
                {
                    if (Column < 4)
                    {
                        return Blocks.UpperLeft;
                    }

                    return Column < 7 ? Blocks.UpperMiddle : Blocks.UpperRight;
                }

                if (Row < 7)
                {
                    if (Column < 4)
                    {
                        return Blocks.MiddleLeft;
                    }

                    return Column < 7 ? Blocks.Middle : Blocks.MiddleRight;
                }

                if (Column < 4)
                {
                    return Blocks.LowerLeft;
                }

                return Column < 7 ? Blocks.LowerMiddle : Blocks.LowerRight;
            }
        }

        public bool IsSolved { get { return Value != null; } }

        public int? Value { get; set; }
        internal List<int> PotentialValues { get; private set; }

        internal Cell(int row, int column)
        {
            Row = row;
            Column = column;
            PotentialValues = values;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this being down voted with no comments?

Comment: I haven't done that but to help you, you haven't displayed BOARD class and what is most important you haven't showen how you are showing that table. You just assigned values but where are you drawing/displaying it?

Comment: OK, I see. That helps me out. This is the first time I have posted on here. I will edit my post and add my Board class and Cell class into the original post. Thank you

Comment: It's being downvoted because all you've done is show some code setting values in an instance of a class called `Board`. We have no idea what `Board` is, we have no idea if there is a display mechanism built into this class, if you're generating an image, printing it, displaying it as ASCII in the console, rendering it as HTML, etc. At the moment, it almost sounds like you expect C# to have some built-in method to display a sudoku board, but I imagine you wouldn't expect that.

Comment: Thanks John. Since this is the first time I've posted on here I did not know exactly the verbage and information I needed to provide up front.

I would like to display this as ASCII in the console so that when I run the program, it will appear as a DOS input that I can type into

Comment: Looking at the code you have posted, you have no code to display your board in any kind of way.

Comment: To clarify for everyone, my Cell class is supposed to handle all logic in cells. My Board class is supposed to define the parameters of the actual board, and my Program class is supposed to fill static information into the Board. Then, the inputs should be taken and cleared logically through the cell class

Comment: You will need to use `Console.Write(...)` and `Console.WriteLine(...)` to output your board, in that case. There's no built in way to do this, so you'll have to build the text output yourself.

Comment: Yes, and that is where I cannot find a specific output for this. I've tried creating a grid (and failed), tried Console.WriteLine(Board) which only displays "Sudoku.Board", and tried to create a List<T> to generate an object from the class

Comment: A class' default "ToString()" method will output its name ("Sudoku.Board"). You can output primitive types (integer, etc.) by first converting them to string. Consider `Console.WriteLine(Board)` - how would .NET understand what you want to be displayed? There's no shortcuts here.

Comment: So I would need to probably put this information into an array and then to Console.WriteLine([the array that holds my board information]) to display the board, and then have overrides for input and a loop to continue to display the updated board.

Is that more in line with what I need to do?

Comment: No, you would have to loop through and write each cell. But yes, you seem to be getting the general idea.

Comment: OK, let me work on that and I will post an update on here. Thanks for helping with the logic behind this. I knew there was something easy I was missing, but most Google results show solvers and not generators, and most generators I feel are getting into sticky code when I'm just looking for a base board to play around with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will provide a basic console output of your board.

```
foreach (var cell in board.Cells)
{
    int x = cell.Column;
    int y = cell.Row;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x * 2, y * 2);
    Console.Write(cell.Value.HasValue ? cell.Value.Value.ToString() : "  ");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

I'm multiplying the X and Y by 2 for the purpose of separating the numbers, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to display the board. Thank you! Now that I can do this I should be able to tinker with the other logic and make sure that it provides an ability for me to actually play. Right now, I have it set to auto-solve

Comment: I gave your post a +1 but since I'm new it won't display, just an FYI