# How to shuffling number on sudoku

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

now I'm learning how to make a sudoku game and i have an issue for randomizing the number on the field when play

my source number is basically `static int[,,]` the question is how do I randomizing this and not have same number in the column and row.

here's the code

```
public static NumberInput[,,] grid = new NumberInput[9, 3, 3];
    public static bool init = false;
    public static string clickedValue;
    public static int btnType;
    public static int chosenValue;
    public GetChildren childScript;
    public static NumberInput cellClicked;
    public static int[] cellCoords = new int[3];
    public static bool eraseCalled = false;
    private int count;
    public static List<int> squares = new List<int>();
    public static List<int> rows = new List<int>();
    public static List<int> columns = new List<int>();
    public static List<string> cellValues = new List<string>();
    public GameObject validatePanel;
    public GameObject restartPanel;
    public GameObject donePanel;
    public GameObject wrongSolutionPanel;
    public GameObject emptySolutionPanel;
    public GameObject correctSolutionPanel;
    public GameObject endpanel;


   static int[,,] sudokuMatrix = { { { 0, 5, 2}, { 0, 0, 6}, { 1, 0, 8} }, { { 0, 7, 1 }, { 0, 4, 0 }, { 0, 0, 2 } }, { { 0, 4, 8}, { 1, 2, 5}, { 7, 0, 9} }, { { 2, 0, 5}, { 8, 0, 4}, { 6, 0, 7} },{ { 4, 9, 0}, { 0, 1, 6}, { 5, 8, 3} }, { { 8, 1, 6}, { 5, 3, 7}, { 2, 0, 4} }, { { 0, 2, 0}, { 7, 6, 1}, { 4, 0, 9} }, { { 7, 6, 4}, { 8, 0, 9}, { 0, 2, 5} }, { { 0, 8, 1}, { 4, 5, 2}, { 0, 7, 3} } };


 void Update()
    {
        if (!init)
            initializeLevel();

        if (eraseCalled)
        {
            childScript.gridcellClicked();
            eraseCalled = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            buttonPressed();

    }

    void initializeLevel()
    {
        validatePanel.SetActive(false);
        restartPanel.SetActive(false);
        donePanel.SetActive(false);
        wrongSolutionPanel.SetActive(false);
        emptySolutionPanel.SetActive(false);
        correctSolutionPanel.SetActive(false);
        count = 0;
        for (int square = 0; square < 9; square++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                {
                    grid[square, row, column] = childScript.cells[count];
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int square = 0; square < 9; square++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                {
                    if (sudokuMatrix[square, row, column] != 0)
                    {
                        grid[square, row, column].txtvalue.text = "" + sudokuMatrix[square, row, column];
                        grid[square, row, column].playable = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grid[square, row, column].txtvalue.text = "";
                        grid[square, row, column].playable = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
        {
            childScript.cells[i].setColor();
            if (childScript.cells[i].playable)
                childScript.cells[i].txtvalue.text = "";
        }

        if (!init)
            init = true;
    }

    public void buttonPressed()
    {

        if (btnType == 0)
        {
            cellCoords[0] = childScript.cells.FindIndex(x => x == cellClicked) / 9;
            cellCoords[1] = (childScript.cells.FindIndex(x => x == cellClicked) / 3) - (3 * cellCoords[0]);
            cellCoords[2] = (childScript.cells.FindIndex(x => x == cellClicked) - (9 * cellCoords[0])) % 3;
            childScript.gridcellClicked();
            btnType = 9;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, for one, not all random arrangements are a valid soduko board.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Sudoku Board Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739808/c-sharp-sudoku-board-generator)